# Подключить файл Jade по условию

Tags: node.js, express, jade

Имеется select в котором находятся несколько option

```
<select>
  <option>страница 1</option>
  <option>страница 2</option>
  ...
<select>
```

После выбора одного из пунктов рендерится страница, в которую вставляется кусок шаблона, соответствующий выбранному пункту. Для каждого такого куска имеется отдельный jade файл. Например: для пункта "страница 1" есть файл page1.jade, для "страница 2" - файл page2.jade и т.д.
Страница рендерится так:

```
res.render('result', option); // В option находится выбранный пункт из select - это свойство page
```

Вопрос: как, в зависимости от выбранного пользователем варианта, вставить нужный файл jade? 
У сделал так:

```
- if (page =="page1")
  // много кода, соответствующего page1
- if (page =="page2")
  // много кода, соответствующего page2
```

и т.д.

Но пункты для select могут потом добавляться, а это значит, что придется добавлять условие для новой страницы. В итоге файл result.jade получается очень огромным.Как еще можно реализовать это по-другому?

Answer (score 1):

Можно применить что-то типа такого:

```
case page
  when "page1": include page1.jade
  when "page2": include page2.jade
  when "page3": include page3.jade
  ...
```

Для получения более подробной информации, обратитесь к документации на [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/reference/case/).